# Array parse causes a recursive send error: Strict standards

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

This is in my recursive function to send parameters by default, this works correctly.

```
    <?php
    function tf_wp_parse_args( &$a, $b ) {
        $a = (array) $a;
        $b = (array) $b;
        $result = $b;
        foreach ( $a as $k => &$v ) {
            if ( is_array( $v ) && isset( $result[ $k ] ) ) {
                $result[ $k ] = tf_wp_parse_args( $v, $result[ $k ] );
            } else {
                $result[ $k ] = $v;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
    // example
    $args = array(
        'name'   => 'name_01_field',
        'params' => array('id'=> 'field_id_01'),
    );
    $defaults = array(
            'name'        => '',
            'title'       => '',
            'description' => '',
            'params'      => array('labels'=>array(),'id' => ''),
    );

    $args = tf_wp_parse_args( isset($args) ? $args : array() , $defaults );

    var_dump( $args );
/*
array (size=4)
  'name' => string 'name_01_field' (length=13)
  'title' => string '' (length=0)
  'description' => string '' (length=0)
  'params' => 
    array (size=2)
      'labels' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'id' => string 'field_id_01' (length=11)
*/
    ?>
```

But if I activate the debug I get the following error:  `Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in` 
https://gyazo.com/05198e763afd4b6859fb1f50bb4935fd

What could be happening?

Comment: if `isset` is not true it gives just an `array()` and that can't be taken as reference. create variable with an empty array and use this.

Comment: **update** 
`$args = tf_wp_parse_args( isset($args) ? $args : array() , $defaults );`
to
`$args = tf_wp_parse_args( $args  , $defaults );` 
Now no shows that error, thank you very much